# How to implement onClickListner in StackView

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I wish to add an onclickListner in my stackView so that it present another fragment,

The fragments would be a simple page containg a textView and an imageView.
There would be 10+ fragments each corresponding to an entry in the StackView .

the stackView in a fragment so it would be probably like calling a fragment from another fragment

My codes are :

**Stack_Adapter.java**

```
public class Stack_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

ArrayList<Stack_Items> arrayList;
LayoutInflater inflater;
ViewHolder holder = null;

public Stack_Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Stack_Items> arrayList) {
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Stack_Items getItem(int pos) {
    return arrayList.get(pos);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int pos) {
    return pos;
}

@Override
public View getView(int pos, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stack_layout, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    holder.text.setText(arrayList.get(pos).getName());
    holder.image.setBackgroundResource(arrayList.get(pos).getImage());

    return view;
}

public class ViewHolder {
    TextView text;
    ImageView image;
} }
```

**EventsFragment.java**

```
public class EventsFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    private StackView stackView;
    private ArrayList<Stack_Items> list;
    TypedArray eventLogo;
    String eventName[];

    @Nullable
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        eventLogo = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.event_stack_icon);
        eventName = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.event_stack);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.events_layout, null);
        stackView = (StackView) view.findViewById(R.id.stackView1);
        list = new ArrayList<Stack_Items>();

        //Adding items to the list
        for (int i = 0; i < eventLogo.length(); i++) {
            list.add(new Stack_Items(eventName[i], eventLogo.getResourceId(i, -1)));
        }
        //Calling adapter and setting it over stackView
        Stack_Adapter adapter = new Stack_Adapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), list);
        stackView.setAdapter(adapter);
        stackView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View
                    view, int position, long id) {
                MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mainActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                switch (stackView.getSelectedItemPosition()) {
                    case 0:
                        Fragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,homeFragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Fragment eventsFragment = new EventsFragment();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,eventsFragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Fragment encoreFragment = new EncoreFragment();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,encoreFragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        break;
            }
        });
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return view;
    }
}
```

**Stack_Items**

```
public class Stack_Items {
String name;
Integer image;

public Stack_Items(String name, Integer image) {
    this.name = name;
    this.image = image;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;

}

public int getImage() {

    return image;
} }
```

**events_layout**

```
<StackView
    android:id="@+id/stackView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true" >
</StackView>
```

**Stack_layout**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

Since there are so many pages & all similar so, I would like to find an easy alternative by linking things in strings.xml , like the linked stack and all..

**EDIT-1**

Updated EventsFragments.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StackView` inherits indirectly from [AdapterView](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html), meaning you can use [setOnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener)) on it, like you would for a `ListView`

Comment: I updated EventsFragments.java , please have a look. stackView.getSelectedItemPosition() always returns 0 , so what's the solution to this.

Comment: use `position` instead

Comment: is there any way to reduce creating tons of fragment  pages both their layout aswell as .java file , something more dynamic , on page that seeks information forma string-array , because on the page there is just a textView and an ImageView

Comment: you can create always an instance of the same Fragment providing the information you want to set in a Bundle

Comment: can you please elaborate , or put the code with bit of explanation ?

Comment: something like [that](https://gist.github.com/bblackbelt/9e68c7bf6a59668c984f) could easy the work

Comment: I replaced the switch with Fragment eventDescFragment = new DynamicEventsPage().newInstance(R.array.event_stack,eventLogo.getResourceId(position, -1)); fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, eventDescFragment); fragmentTransaction.commit(); but how do i get id of the string eventName , to be passed because R.array.event_stack didn't work , App force closed giving error at the new fragment file?